# custom query daily count with momentjs in strapi

Tags: node.js, api, strapi

I have a collection of articles that have title, content, and last_post_date, and I have a custom query that gets the daily count for it. For example, `find-articles-count-by-date?from=2021-08-01&to=2021-08-31`, then I expect it will show the daily count for each day, but it turns out to return a duplicate date. How can I fix it?

My custom query code

```
const moment = require("moment");

module.exports = {
  async find(ctx) {
    // getting the query params
    let { from, to } = ctx.query;

    // querying the articles according to the dates
    const articles = await strapi
      .query("article")
      .find({ last_post_date_gte: from, last_post_date_lte: to, _limit: -1 });

    // converting the date to date objects for calculation
    from = moment(from);
    to = moment(to);

    let yearly = false,
      monthly = false;

    if (to.diff(from, "year") > 0) {
      yearly = true;
      monthly = false;
    } else if (to.diff(from, "month") > 0) {
      monthly = true;
      yearly = false;
    }

    let dates = [];

    // getting list of unique dates
    articles.map((article) => {
      // refactoringi the article date
      let articleDate = article.last_post_date;

      if (yearly) {
        // will return the year of the date
        articleDate = moment(articleDate).year();
      } else if (monthly) {
        // will return the month of the date
        articleDate = moment(articleDate).format("MMMM");
      }

      if (!dates.includes(articleDate)) {
        dates.push(articleDate);
      }
    });

    // getting article counts of each dates
    let result = dates.map((date) => {
      let count = 0;

      // mapping through the articles if date matches
      // if it matches count is increased;
      articles.map((article) => {
        let articleDate = article.last_post_date;
        if (yearly) {
          articleDate = moment(articleDate).year();
        } else if (monthly) {
          articleDate = moment(articleDate).format("MMMM");
        }

        if (articleDate == date) {
          count++;
        }
      });

      return {
        last_post_date: date,
        count,
      };
    });

    ctx.send(result);
  },
};
```

Given result with duplicate DateTime, supposed to be day by day.

```
[
{
"last_post_date": "2021-08-01T16:00:00.000Z",
"count": 2
},
{
"last_post_date": "2021-08-01T22:26:00.000Z",
"count": 1
},
{
"last_post_date": "2021-08-02T00:00:00.000Z",
"count": 1
},
{
"last_post_date": "2021-08-02T16:00:00.000Z",
"count": 1
},
{
"last_post_date": "2021-08-02T17:00:01.000Z",
"count": 1
},
{
"last_post_date": "2021-08-03T05:09:00.000Z",
"count": 1
},
{
"last_post_date": "2021-08-03T06:42:00.000Z",
"count": 1
},
{
"last_post_date": "2021-08-03T06:50:00.000Z",
"count": 1
},
{
"last_post_date": "2021-08-03T07:27:00.000Z",
"count": 1
},
{
"last_post_date": "2021-08-03T16:00:00.000Z",
"count": 1
},
{
"last_post_date": "2021-08-03T16:00:01.000Z",
"count": 1
},
{
"last_post_date": "2021-08-04T11:01:00.000Z",
"count": 1
},
{
"last_post_date": "2021-08-04T17:00:00.000Z",
"count": 2
}]
```

Comment: Could you attach the response of this query? `const articles = await strapi.query("article").find({ last_post_date_gte: from, last_post_date_lte: to, _limit: -1 });`? Would be simpler to debug.

Comment: Can you please double check your `if (to.diff(from, "year") > 0)` & `if (to.diff(from, "month") > 0)` conditions? I don't think it's going inside them as the date in the final result still contains timestamp. Whereas as per your code it should be the year or month name that should be going into the dates array.

Comment: Finally, I changed the date type to date instead of DateTime. Thank you for your reply.